# Post apocalyptic cartoon about a robot girl who finds a radio in a junkyard

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, post-apocalyptic

I remember watching a cartoon when I was a young kid probably between years 1998-2004. I don't remember the plot but I think that it was post apocalyptic.

The main character (maybe even the only character) was a girl with a short straight bob (blonde I think) and I'm pretty sure she was a robot. I know for a fact she wore overalls.

The only other detail I remember is that she found a radio in a junkyard or something and she always listened to music with it. It might be foreign/not U.S made.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "Battle Angel Alita"? The main character is a girl who is a cyborg. She has a black, straight bob and lives in a place called The Scrapyard, parts of which are basically a big junkyard. I’m more familiar with the manga but there were 2 episodes of a video animation made in the nineties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm four years late, but the cartoon you are looking for might be based on the manga Yokohama Kaidashi Kikou, it has a short anime-adaptation :)

The main character is a robot, that lives in post-apocalyptic Japan. She travels around in a scooter and one of her friends has a short blonde bob. It's a very nice, calm slice-of-life manga.

Comment: Can you confirm any other details? Maybe provide an image from the mange or anime adaptation that shows a picture. Can you confirm the overalls, as a point the author specifically recalls? These would help boost your answer. Thankfully there is never too late, hopefully the person asking sees your answer and can say whether you were right or not!